# The If statement is being ignored in my javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<form action="demo_form_method_post.asp" method="POST" target="_blank">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

if (method="POST") {
  alert("YES");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ok so I put the method="POST" above to make the statement. 
Then in the If statement, I put `if("method = POST")` then there would be an alert saying YES.
But if I Iput POST or GET I still get the alert.
I tried the double == and the triple === but then I don't get the alert at all? My only goal in those script is to get a response from the method = "post"

Comment: You may want to review JavaScript a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just reference `method` and have the browser know what you're talking about. If you want to check a form's method, try using `document.forms`.

In this case, since you only have one form, you'd write:

```
if (document.forms[0].method == "POST") {
    alert("YES");
 }
```

Comment: Switching out the `=` for an `==` is also important.

Answer (score 0):

POST data is only available server side. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6486141/4347337).
If you simply want to see when a form is submitted and has method=post, you can just attach to the submit event, and check the method property.

[Try this JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/o86p613w/)

```
<form method="POST" id="myform">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
        alert("The form is being submitted using method=" + this.method);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Use `this.method` over jQuery's slower, uglier, `$(this).attr('method')`

Comment: While the first sentence is 'correct' this doesn't address the OP's code (or failure of it working).

Answer (score 0):

You can check method post like this as well

```
<form id="myForm" action="demo_form_method_post.asp" method="POST" target="_blank">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
  if(document.getElementById("myForm").method == "post") {
    alert("YES");
  }
</script>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qkvczfkg/3/)

Or using jquery

```
if($("#myForm").attr("method") == 'POST'){
    alert("YES");
}
```